# aes-128-ctr is not available

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, private-key, keystore

While trying to extract key from keystore file using password, using the library [keythereum](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum), I'm getting the error:

`aes-128-ctr is not available`

I'm using `web3` version `^0.19.1`.

Ref: https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum/issues/73

Comment: Show your code please. BTW, it is not clear why you need `aes-128-ctr` for, but you can do this with `keythereum.recover`.

Comment: My key is using aes-128-ctr which keythereum is not able to recover.

Comment: weird part is that it works on a standalone code. But throws this error when copying the same code to our main codebase.

Comment: Perhaps it is something from your environment like node vs browser, or a different dependency.